# How Can I make my angular ui building dynamic based on the set of Permission?

Tags: angular, spring, permissions

I am developing an Employee Management System with Angular as a frontend and Java Spring Boot as a backend.Currently system has static set of roles and based on the role given to the user he/she can interact with the system. But there are many cases that require seprate role during runtime, but defining new role via code each time seems tidious. I am planning to create a ui page for the system admin from where he/she can define user groups and also grant and revoke permission to the group if required. He/she can assign user a group or multiple groups. Based on that Distinct Permission can be obtained.In backend I have created a schema maintaining set of permissions and endpoints associated with them. Currently In backend the required part is working. But at angular I am seeking for a dynamic implementation instead of fixing the condition checking in template code.
Currently In my spring security , I have mapped end points with Permissions associated to them. I want to make Angular code dynamic with minimum `*ngIf` at template code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look for `canActivate` in angular and inplement `guard`. Then you can activate some path only for specific user role witouth using `*ngIf` in components.
Docs https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: In the same route, there might be components that need to be displayed conditionally.

Comment: ok, so look at https://www.geekstrick.com/view-component-based-on-user-role/
They made a directive for user role ad use it like *ngIf. in this case you don't need guard. Hope this can help you